# Sorting a Column of String Values Representing Numbers in Access (VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

**The Scenario:** I have a table In Access that has a column of type `text` but contains numerical values that needs to be sorted in a descending order.

**The Issue:** I tried doing a query and specifying the order in the design view, but the results are being sorted based on the first digit and not the whole number.

When I tried to change the type of the column from `text` to `numeric`, I received a warning some data will be lost and also the sorting yielded wrong results.

**The Question:** Any suggestions about how to solve this issue?

**Note:** I am importing the data from an excel sheet where the column is of type `standard`.

Answer (score 0):

I find no datatype `NUMERIC` in the Access SQL documentation. If data will be lost, you use a datatype that is too small for the converted values. Probably use `FLOAT`, a double precision floating point value. You could add a `FLOAT` column to your table and then `UPDATE` that field of the table from the text field. This will preserve your old values and lets you check for any non-converted values.

```
UPDATE myTable SET float_field=text_field;
```